# when using tc-prio i have starvation issues on my lowest band what can i do to solve it?

Tags: linux-kernel

Im using TC to prioritize the traffic in my network.
i need to prioritize based on TOS however the lowest band is causing starvation to the higher band.
now i know that there is a known bug and this is how tc prio works but i wonder if anyone was able to resolve this issue.

I have 8 bands and traffic is classified properly to different bands however i can see that higher bands are dropping packets even if they utiliza less bandwidth then my link bandwidth.

I wonder if there is a way to limit the time that the prio will dequeue packets from the queues

will be happy to get your help.

i tried already attaching a limit qdisc but the problem is that i cant know what will be the speed of the traffic in the lowest priority i cannot limit the speed i need to limit based on amount of packets or time.